# Question about using ordering operations in function with polymorphic type signatures

Tags: haskell

Hi I'm new to haskell and I created a function to compute the absolute value of a number.

```hs
absVal :: (Num a) => a -> a
absVal x
    | x < 0     = x - x - x
    | otherwise = x
```

this code gives me an error (what kind of error is this called?) 
"Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘<’ "

But when I rewrite the function as

```hs
absVal :: (Ord a) => a -> a
absVal x
    | x < 0     = x - x - x
    | otherwise = x
```

I get the error "Could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal ‘0’ "

When I write the type signature as Float -> Float the function works as intended

Why is this?

Comment: Normally one would expect `Num` to be a subclass of `Ord` but not all `Num` class member types are orderable i.e. complex numbers. So you have to mention both constraints in the signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator `-` (subtraction) requires the `Num` class, and so does the literal `0` (zero). Operator `<` (less) requires the `Ord` class. Since you're using all three of them in your function, both classes are required.

You can specify several classes by tupling them like this:

```
absVal :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
```

Changing the type to `Float` works, because `Float` does have instances of both `Num` and `Ord`

Comment: You can also Curry constraints! `Num a => Ord a => a -> a` but nobody does that for some reason

Comment: In PureScript that's the only way, and I have come to find it less pleasant to look at @luqui